# MS Bot Framework application throws error as "Sorry,my code is having an issue" for hosted BOT

Tags: bots, botframework

I have one BOT application, it works well on localhost when working with the emulator.
But when the same bot is hosted on a server and when trying to chat from WEBCHAT channel with Bot it throws an error.

My BOT application is using 3 different LUIS application the these LUIS apps are not expired.
Amazing thing is that LUIS application picks right intent and shows me right  PromptDialog, but on the next line "Sorry, my code is having an issue" this msg appears.
Due to which I am not able to proceed with the further conversation.

It is happening with all the functionality of the BOT.
What can be reason behind this issue?

Comment: As we are not magicians / mediums, we need that you edit your question and produce details about your implementation if you want some help

Comment: Post your bot code that reproduces this issue so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to do the following:
1) Go to My Bots -> Connect to channels and click on the channel which is having an issue. The error message may shed some light on what is going on
[image]
2) Investigate the machine which hosts the application. In case of `Azure` enabling `Diagnostic Logs` may help

3) Anyway you need to introduce logging layer for your application, to make sure you'll be able to investigate further issues quickly. There are many solutions you may proceed with like `NLog` or `log4net`.

I'd say that point 3 must be a first step anyway, since you are dealing with external thing like `botframework` and who knows what can be changed in this black box. So logging is drastically important and prevents you or anybody else from guessing what may went wrong